# Link sends me to the wrong page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to create a link to the Products controller but I seem to be doing something wrong.Here is my code:

```
@Html.ActionLink(subcategory, "Products")
```

When I click this link I want to be sent to something like this :

```
http://localhost:2100/Products
```

Instead I get sent to this page:

```
http://localhost:2100/Home/Products
```

If I open the Product page cotontroller and click the link I get sent herE:

```
http://localhost:2100/Products/Products
```

So how can I solve this problem cinsidering the fact that the link is in the _Layout.cshtml view?

Comment: When posting a question that are related to routing it would be helpful if you will supply the route config code too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are setting the action part of route. Use this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(subcategory, "Index", "Products")
```

**EDIT**

See the method's signature that you are using:

```
Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
```

The overload you are using is this one:

```
Html.ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName)
```

That means in this overload, you dont set the controller part of route. So, when we do not set a part of a route, it will be read automatically from current route that means: when we are in a route that it's controller is `Home`, your link's controller will be `Home` and you will get this route:

```
@Html.ActionLink(subcategory, "Products", "Home")
```

and when your are in a route with controller `Products`, you will get this route:

```
@Html.ActionLink(subcategory, "Products", "Products")
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) has the following syntax :

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
string linkText,
string actionName,
string controllerName
)
```

As rightly answered by [Javad_Amiry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645167/javad-amiry) you can use the following code to create the link :

```
@Html.ActionLink(subcategory, "Index", "Products")
```

where,
subcategory : content from this will be used to create the linkText
"Index" : Is the action name.
"Products" : Is the controller name.

It would have been easier to help you out, had to posted the route config code too.